# Menu bar refresh issue in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a Menu bar with two options - Store and Order, implemented using the below Anchor tags.

```
<a href="#/store/">Store</a>
<a href="#/order/">Order</a>
```

I am using the normal Angular Route provider which works fine.

However, if I am on Store, and click it again, the view doesn't get refreshed.

Somehow, I was able to figure this out on Stackoverflow, where it was suggested to perform a Route reload on each click.

```
<a href="#/store/" ng-click="reload()">Store</a>
<a href="#/order/" ng-click="reload()">Order</a>

$scope.reload = function() {
    $route.reload;
}
```

This does the job, but now the problem is if I am on Store and click Order, the current Store view gets refreshed first and then the Order View is rendered.

How do I achieve the below requirements:

1). When the user is on Store and clicks Store again, the Store View gets refreshed.

2). However. when the user is on Store, and clicks Order, the Store view should not reload but directly render the Order view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `$location` service to compare if it is same route or different

```
<a href="#/store/" ng-click="reload('/store/')">Store</a>
<a href="#/order/" ng-click="reload('/order/')">Order</a>

$scope.reload = function(url) {
      if ($location.path().search(url) !== -1) {
          // it is same route
          $route.reload();
      }
}
```